# Ordering MYSQL result basing on a condition

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a query which gives this output:

```
ID |product | value | type
-----------------
65 | truck  | 4000  | kg
66 | truck  | 3000  | kg
67 | truck  | 7000  | mt
68 | truck  | 800   | mt
69 | crane  | 2000  | kg
70 | crane  | 3000  | kg
71 | crane  | 1000  | mt
72 | crane  | 500   | mt
```

I need it to be ordered by product, by type, and then the numeric values need to be ordered depending on their corresponding type.
So numbers must be desc if 'kg' and asc if 'mt'.
I need the previous table to be ordered like this:

```
ID |product | value | type
-----------------
65 | truck  | 4000  | kg
66 | truck  | 3000  | kg
67 | truck  | 800   | mt
68 | truck  | 7000  | mt
69 | crane  | 3000  | kg
70 | crane  | 2000  | kg
71 | crane  | 500   | mt
72 | crane  | 1000  | mt
```

How can I solve this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the `order by` as:

```
order by product,
         (type = 'kg') desc,
         (case when type = 'kg' then value end) desc,
         value asc
```

The second expression puts all the `kg` rows first (for each product).  The third orders the `kg` rows descending.  The final orders the rest (`'mt'`) ascending.

Answer (score 1):

You can use different orders

order by product,

type,

(case when type = 'mt' then value desc

else value asc end)